# Team Foundation Server on Windows Server 2008 Server Core installation?

Tags: windows-server-2008, team-foundation-server, windows-server-core

I'd love to get a stripped down TFS install on a virtual machine, which is why I'm thinking about this.

I know R2 comes with the CLR and a subset of a framework, so that limitation is (possibly?) gone, so it might be possible.

Does anybody have any information on doing this?  Have you tired it?  I'm not seeing much on google about getting this done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install .NET framework on 2008 Server Core so if the application requires it it won't install on Core.  Saying that, 2008 Core doesn't actually use a whole lot less resources than the standard version - it just has a much smaller attack footprint so it should run pretty decently in a VM anyway.

Answer (score 1):

TFS is not supported on Server Core due to the graphical requirement, as well as the need for Windows SharePoint Server. TFS 2010 also has a new MMC snap-in to manage the server and is also not supported on Core due to the heavy prerequisites.

Confirmation of the Build Servers being support on Core will possibly be confirmed upon release.